# Resume/CV Parsing in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, lamp, text-parsing

We are developing a requirement base social media site using LAMP.

For that we want to do Resume/CV Parsing in PHP.

We were able to parse Email-id and Phone, but not sure how to parse the other information like full name, address, education, employment etc from the resume.

Plus resume/CV can be in various formats like doc,html,rtf,txt etc.

Anyone know abt the PHP script, where we can grab the data. or any development idea to kick start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get that information from any arbitrarily formatted resume? Sounds like mission impossible to me.

Comment: This is a **hard problem**. There is no easy way to parse all resumes; no such program exists even at the big job boards and recruiter websites. Their importers are always messy and do can't handle a large percentage of the stuff that gets uploaded. I hope you budgeted at least a couple weeks of developer hours to even attempt this.

Comment: Why don't you simply create a CV web form of your own and put it online on your website? You would of course have to create a layout as general as possible to accommodate the needs of all applicants but on the other hand you would have a way to store all the data directly in your database without the need to use any kind of potentially inaccurate CV parsers. Not to mention the  benefits of storing data inside a database like sorting, querying etc.

Answer (score 5):

I would see if an existing resume parser has an API you can use or a custom hook you can add to your framework. Check out [Sovren](http://www.sovren.com) or [TextKernel](http://www.textkernel.com/hr_solutions.php)

According to Sovren's website, they quote:

> Once your instance of the SovrenConvertAndParse Web Service is
>   running, you will access it via SOAP. Almost all programming
>   environments have the ability to auto-create a web service client or
>   web service proxy automatically from the web service’s WSDL. We also
>   have sample clients for some environments such as PHP. In any case,
>   creating the web service client should be a very quick task: usually a
>   few minutes, maybe a few hours.
>
> Once you have created your web service client, you can call a single
>   method on the web service to convert and parse a resume in one
>   operation, receiving HR-XML output in return.

http://www.sovren.com/sovren-products-parser-implementation.php

http://www.sovren.com/sovren-products-web-service.php

TextKernel quotes:

> Document processing for all types of documents (DOC, DOCX, PDF, RTF,
>   HTML, TIFF, TXT, XML, MSG, and EML type documents). Textkernel offers the following 11 languages out of the box: English, German, French, Dutch, Spanish, Swedish, Danish, Polish, Romanian, Italian, Slovak.

It seems their web interface is called Sourcebox:

> Sourcebox is fully configurable with Extract!, Textkernel's CV
>   Parsing software.
>
> Sourcebox has a multilingual web interface for staff to manage the
>   CV queue and manually check and correct exceptions.
>
> Sourcebox can be used as an interface to many leading CRM, ATS,
>   Matching engines, HRMS systems and your own website or recruitment
>   portal.

http://www.textkernel.com/hr_solutions.php?nav=sourcebox

They both seem promising enough to utilize and not have to reinvent the wheel here, especially with PHP.

Comment: @Maverick  seems you missed [RChilli](http://www.rchilli.com)  and Hireability into your discussions.  We implemented both RChilli and Hireability for our customers, and found RChilli team is more proactive and helpful from all other players.