# store resume data in database and convert it to excel format later

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to store the resume data directly in the database using php & mysql ??

If someone is uploading a resume , the data should go directly to the database, which we can download in excel format ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6913165/2518525

Comment: that's the problem.. all resumes are not in same format .. so how can i match the fields ??